# Creating sticky sliding icons at the left using css

Tags: html, css

I need to create almost the same sticky sliding icon set in both left and right using css. The right side icon with text is working perfectly but the left sided is not.

see code snippet

```css
.sticky-container{
  /*background-color: #333;*/
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  right: -119px;
  /*top:230px;*/
  width: 200px;

 }

 .sticky li{
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #efefef;
  height: 43px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px 0px 1px 0px;
  -webkit-transition:all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition:all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition:all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
 

 }

 .sticky li:hover{
  margin-left: -115px;
  /*-webkit-transform: translateX(-115px);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-115px);
  -o-transform: translateX(-115px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-115px);
  transform:translateX(-115px);*/
  /*background-color: #8e44ad;*/
 
 }

 .sticky li img{
  float: left;
  margin: 5px 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;

 }

 .sticky li p{
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 43px;

 }




 .sticky-container-first{
  /*background-color: #333;*/
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  left: -119px;
  /*top:230px;*/
  width: 200px;

 }

 .sticky-first li{
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #efefef;
  height: 43px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px 0px 1px 0px;
  -webkit-transition:all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition:all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition:all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;


 }

 .sticky-first li:hover{
  margin-right: -115px;
  /*-webkit-transform: translateX(115px);
  -moz-transform: translateX(115px);
  -o-transform: translateX(115px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(115px);
  transform:translateX(115px);*/
  /*background-color: #8e44ad;*/
}
 .sticky-first li img{
  float: right;
  margin: 5px 5px;
  margin-left: 10px;

 }

 .sticky-first li p{
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 43px;

 }
```

```html
<div class="sticky-container">
  <ul class="sticky">
   <li>
    <img width="32" height="32" title="" alt="" src="http://new.praavahealth.com/public/images/icon/female.png" />
    <p>Facebook</p>
   </li>
   <li>
    <img width="32" height="32" title="" alt="" src="http://new.praavahealth.com/public/images/icon/female.png" />
    <p>Twitter</p>
   </li>
   <li>
    <img width="32" height="32" title="" alt="" src="http://new.praavahealth.com/public/images/icon/female.png" />
    <p>Pinterest</p>
   </li>
 
  
  </ul>
 </div>

 <div class="sticky-container-first">
  <ul class="sticky-first">
   <li>
    <img width="32" height="32" title="" alt="" src="http://new.praavahealth.com/public/images/icon/female.png" />
    <p>Facebook</p>
   </li>
   <li>
    <img width="32" height="32" title="" alt="" src="http://new.praavahealth.com/public/images/icon/female.png" />
    <p>Twitter</p>
   </li>
   <li>
    <img width="32" height="32" title="" alt="" src="http://new.praavahealth.com/public/images/icon/female.png" />
    <p>Pinterest</p>
   </li>
 
  
  </ul>
 </div>
```

The demo page is http://new.praavahealth.com/ I need the sliding icons work in both left and right side. Please help me
Thanks is advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need to change

```
.sticky-container-first {
    left: -155px;
}
```

```css
.sticky-container{
  /*background-color: #333;*/
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  right: -119px;
  /*top:230px;*/
  width: 200px;

 }
/* style p when hover li */
.sticky-first li:hover p {
    float: right;
}
 .sticky li{
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #efefef;
  height: 43px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px 0px 1px 0px;
  -webkit-transition:all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition:all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition:all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
 

 }

 .sticky li:hover{
  margin-left: -115px;
  /*-webkit-transform: translateX(-115px);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-115px);
  -o-transform: translateX(-115px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-115px);
  transform:translateX(-115px);*/
  /*background-color: #8e44ad;*/
 
 }

 .sticky li img{
  float: left;
  margin: 5px 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;

 }

 .sticky li p{
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 43px;

 }




 .sticky-container-first{
  /*background-color: #333;*/
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  left: -155px;
  /*top:230px;*/
  width: 200px;

 }

 .sticky-first li{
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #efefef;
  height: 43px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px 0px 1px 0px;
  -webkit-transition:all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition:all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition:all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;


 }

 .sticky-first li:hover{
  margin-right: -115px;
  /*-webkit-transform: translateX(115px);
  -moz-transform: translateX(115px);
  -o-transform: translateX(115px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(115px);
  transform:translateX(115px);*/
  /*background-color: #8e44ad;*/
}
 .sticky-first li img{
  float: right;
  margin: 5px 5px;
  margin-left: 10px;

 }

 .sticky-first li p{
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 43px;

 }
```

```html
<div class="sticky-container">
  <ul class="sticky">
   <li>
    <img width="32" height="32" title="" alt="" src="http://new.praavahealth.com/public/images/icon/female.png" />
    <p>Facebook</p>
   </li>
   <li>
    <img width="32" height="32" title="" alt="" src="http://new.praavahealth.com/public/images/icon/female.png" />
    <p>Twitter</p>
   </li>
   <li>
    <img width="32" height="32" title="" alt="" src="http://new.praavahealth.com/public/images/icon/female.png" />
    <p>Pinterest</p>
   </li>
 
  
  </ul>
 </div>

 <div class="sticky-container-first">
  <ul class="sticky-first">
   <li>
    <img width="32" height="32" title="" alt="" src="http://new.praavahealth.com/public/images/icon/female.png" />
    <p>Facebook</p>
   </li>
   <li>
    <img width="32" height="32" title="" alt="" src="http://new.praavahealth.com/public/images/icon/female.png" />
    <p>Twitter</p>
   </li>
   <li>
    <img width="32" height="32" title="" alt="" src="http://new.praavahealth.com/public/images/icon/female.png" />
    <p>Pinterest</p>
   </li>
 
  
  </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `text-align: right;` to the `<p>`-tags on the left side.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. Text is in position now but the ul block should be at the absolute left so that only icons can be seen without hovering .

Answer (score 0):

try adding this class `.sticky-first li:hover p { float: right;}` when hover on `li`

```css
.sticky-container{
  /*background-color: #333;*/
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  right: -119px;
  /*top:230px;*/
  width: 200px;

 }
/* style p when hover li */
.sticky-first li:hover p {
    float: right;
}
 .sticky li{
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #efefef;
  height: 43px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px 0px 1px 0px;
  -webkit-transition:all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition:all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition:all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
 

 }

 .sticky li:hover{
  margin-left: -115px;
  /*-webkit-transform: translateX(-115px);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-115px);
  -o-transform: translateX(-115px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-115px);
  transform:translateX(-115px);*/
  /*background-color: #8e44ad;*/
 
 }

 .sticky li img{
  float: left;
  margin: 5px 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;

 }

 .sticky li p{
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 43px;

 }




 .sticky-container-first{
  /*background-color: #333;*/
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  left: -119px;
  /*top:230px;*/
  width: 200px;

 }

 .sticky-first li{
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #efefef;
  height: 43px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px 0px 1px 0px;
  -webkit-transition:all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition:all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition:all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;


 }

 .sticky-first li:hover{
  margin-right: -115px;
  /*-webkit-transform: translateX(115px);
  -moz-transform: translateX(115px);
  -o-transform: translateX(115px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(115px);
  transform:translateX(115px);*/
  /*background-color: #8e44ad;*/
}
 .sticky-first li img{
  float: right;
  margin: 5px 5px;
  margin-left: 10px;

 }

 .sticky-first li p{
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 43px;

 }
```

```html
<div class="sticky-container">
  <ul class="sticky">
   <li>
    <img width="32" height="32" title="" alt="" src="http://new.praavahealth.com/public/images/icon/female.png" />
    <p>Facebook</p>
   </li>
   <li>
    <img width="32" height="32" title="" alt="" src="http://new.praavahealth.com/public/images/icon/female.png" />
    <p>Twitter</p>
   </li>
   <li>
    <img width="32" height="32" title="" alt="" src="http://new.praavahealth.com/public/images/icon/female.png" />
    <p>Pinterest</p>
   </li>
 
  
  </ul>
 </div>

 <div class="sticky-container-first">
  <ul class="sticky-first">
   <li>
    <img width="32" height="32" title="" alt="" src="http://new.praavahealth.com/public/images/icon/female.png" />
    <p>Facebook</p>
   </li>
   <li>
    <img width="32" height="32" title="" alt="" src="http://new.praavahealth.com/public/images/icon/female.png" />
    <p>Twitter</p>
   </li>
   <li>
    <img width="32" height="32" title="" alt="" src="http://new.praavahealth.com/public/images/icon/female.png" />
    <p>Pinterest</p>
   </li>
 
  
  </ul>
 </div>
```